# Forward media attachments in Twilio studio

Tags: twilio

I am setting up a workflow to forward all incoming text messages to zendesk.  I used the send message widget and in the body added:

```
BODY: {{trigger.message.Body}}
MEDIA: {{trigger.message.Media}}
```

The body sends as expected.  But I cannot get the media to send.  I would even take a URL that directs to where the media is.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!  It is:

```
{{trigger.message.MediaUrl0}}
```

You can then use that also in that exact text in the Media URL field and it works!